# Is there a way to generate rowdata from JSON with a passed in schema argument in SQL Server?

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am looking into storing JSON data from disparate sources into SQL server 2016.
Ideally the table structure would have the JSON field to hold the data as well as 
an optional JSON Schema field that if populated would provide the explicit
JSON schema to allow the data to be returned as a table in the with clause.

I couldn't find a solution to use stored schema
I know that an inline table value function can be created, but the issue is that
the schema may vary for each record.

What I want to do is pass the json data and output schema to a function or a stored procedure.
If the output schema is not null then SQL server can apply the output schema to the json data 
and return rowsets otherwise just show the JSON as text.

The closest I could get to the desired results was by using sp_executesql,
but I would have thought that there would be Built in support for this, but I couldn't find any examples here or from Microsoft.

Using the SQL from microsoft docs example where they were using the with clause

[JSON data from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql):

**Create the JSON data and Desired Schema**

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =   
  N'[  
       {  
         "Order": {  
           "Number":"SO43659",  
           "Date":"2011-05-31T00:00:00"  
         },  
         "AccountNumber":"AW29825",  
         "Item": {  
           "Price":2024.9940,  
           "Quantity":1  
         }  
       },  
       {  
         "Order": {  
           "Number":"SO43661",  
           "Date":"2011-06-01T00:00:00"  
         },  
         "AccountNumber":"AW73565",  
         "Item": {  
           "Price":2024.9940,  
           "Quantity":3  
         }  
      }  
 ]'  

DECLARE @jsonOutputSchema NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @jsonOutputSchema = N'
          Number   varchar(200) ''$.Order.Number'',  
          Date     datetime     ''$.Order.Date'',  
          Customer varchar(200) ''$.AccountNumber'',  
          Quantity int          ''$.Item.Quantity'''
```

**Code to parse results to table if output schema exists**

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
     ,@parmlist NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT * FROM  
OPENJSON ( @z_json )  
WITH ( ' + @jsonOutputSchema + ')'

SELECT @parmlist = N'
 @z_json nvarchar(max)   
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @parmlist, @json
```

This works and while the schema will be system generated and not exposed to public users
it is kludgy and seems to be suceptible to SQL injection:

```
SET @jsonOutputSchema = @jsonOutputSchema + '); SELECT @@SERVERNAME, SYSTEM_USER, @@VERSION --'
```

If there were a way to parameterize the WITH clause it would be ideal.  It tried making it a parameter within the sql variable, but that didn't work.  I looked into the JSON_VALUE function to see if it could be used, but I can't come up with a solution to strongly type the fields instead it returns text.

I was hoping to limit this to SQL, but it appears that I may have to 
parse the data externally then pass the rowset(s) back to SQL.  The current schemas defined are currently 7, but appear to be growing.  Some schemas are based on tables we control while others are based on other internal systems.

Any suggestions, ideas or workaround are welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is that the structure of your result set isn't defined until runtime, which always requires dynamic SQL. SQL Server has no support for parameterized schemas because the optimizer can't work with dynamic result sets. In a nutshell, your data isn't even *relational* if the structure varies per row, so no result set is possible. None of this solves your problem, but it goes some way towards explaining why there's no easy way to do this out of the box -- it's a "not designed for this" thing.

Comment: Consider not going against the grain and using actual tables and columns, or else not demanding that SQL Server operate as (essentially) a NoSQL system. Incidentally, a NoSQL database of some sort may be a better fit for what you're doing. Depending on how much truly relational data you have that has to combine with it, of course.

Comment: @ Jeroen Mostert  Yeah a Mongo DB or Raven DB might be the best place. Then service api to get the data and process as needed.  I was hoping to have the data in SQL server to limit the number of hops for data.   I know we can get it into Elasticsearch, but the Java developer has alot of things on his plate and the eventual destination would need to be SQL to be used with relational data or make more data.   We may have to require xml with xsd schema or build adapters to transform or just have SQL hold the data as text then ETL the data.  There goes my initial time estimate.